# Strange behavior using getchar() and -O3

Tags: c++, c, getchar

I have these two functions

```
    void set_dram_channel_width(int channel_width){
      printf("one\n");
          getchar();
    }


    void set_dram_transaction_granularity(int cacheline_size){
      printf("two\n");
          getchar();
    }
    //output:
    one
    f //my keyboard input
    two
    one
    f  //keyboard input
    two
    one
    f  //keyboard input
    //No more calls
```

Then I change the functions to:

```
    void set_dram_channel_width(int channel_width){
      printf("one\n");
    }


    void set_dram_transaction_granularity(int cacheline_size){
      printf("two\n");
      getchar();
    }
    //output
    one
    two 
    f //keyboard input
    //No more calls
```

Both functions are called by an external code, the code for both programs is the same, just changing the getchar() I get those two different outputs. Is this possible or there is something that is really wrong in my code?

Thanks

This is the output I get with GDB**

*For the first code*

```
(gdb) break mem-dram.c:374
Breakpoint 1 at 0x71c810: file build/ALPHA_FS/mem/dramsim/mem-dram.c, line 374.
(gdb) break mem-dram.c:381
Breakpoint 2 at 0x71c7b0: file build/ALPHA_FS/mem/dramsim/mem-dram.c, line 381.
(gdb) run -d ./tmp/MyBench2/ 
one
f
[Switching to Thread 47368811512112 (LWP 17507)]

Breakpoint 1, set_dram_channel_width (channel_width=64)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
two
one
f

Breakpoint 2, set_dram_transaction_granularity (cacheline_size=64)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, set_dram_channel_width (channel_width=8)
374     void set_dram_channel_width(int channel_width){
(gdb) c
Continuing.
two
one
f
```

*For the second code*

```
(gdb) break mem-dram.c:374
Breakpoint 1 at 0x71c7b6: file build/ALPHA_FS/mem/dramsim/mem-dram.c, line 374.
(gdb) break mem-dram.c:380
Breakpoint 2 at 0x71c7f0: file build/ALPHA_FS/mem/dramsim/mem-dram.c, line 380.
(gdb) run
one
two
f
[Switching to Thread 46985688772912 (LWP 17801)]

Breakpoint 1, set_dram_channel_width (channel_width=64)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, set_dram_transaction_granularity (cacheline_size=64)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, set_dram_channel_width (channel_width=8)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Comment: post the external code as well

Comment: ... by which Neil means - we need to see main()

Comment: You've not given us the information we need to help you.  Specifically, we can't see the main program, or other calling code.
It is not clear where the 'f' comes from - probably, it is what you are entering on the keyboard, but we need to know for sure.

Comment: Can you please show the function calls foo1() and foo2().  I can't see how the two sample outputs you give can be produced by the same calling sequence.  It would also be useful to distinguish between what you and what the program outputs.

Comment: ... "distinguish between what you TYPE and what the program outputs".  Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I will post the code in a while, it is going to take me a little because this is a big program and it is not my code

Comment: I hope the gdb output is enough

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is some kind of elaborate joke.

Comment: I wish is a joke, I have decided now to do as if that thing never happened. And when I will have more time I will keep exploring I am intrigue to know why I am getting that problem. Thx for all

Comment: Well as rewritten, it's pretty clear that set_dram_channel_width() and set_dram_transaction_granularity() do more than just getchar() and printf(). The meat of the problem is surely there.

Comment: There are some stuff but there are just assignments to global variables, but certainly the problem should be there. I will explore this when I will have more time. Thx

Answer (score 5):

Since you haven't provided the external code (yet?), here's a guess.

```
while(some condition) {
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

- foo1 prints '`one`' then waits for some input. You type '`f[enter]`'.
- foo1 consumes the '`f`'.
- foo2 prints 'two' then consumes the `[enter]` (a newline character).
- Then you go back to the start, and it all happens again.

With your second version, foo1() doesn't read anything any more.

So:

- foo1 prints '`one`'
- foo2 prints '`two`' then waits for some input. You type '`f[enter]`'
- foo2 consumes the '`f`'

The only remaining question is why it stops when it does. To help you with that, we'd have to see what `(some condition)` actually is.

Note that it's fairly unusual to call `getchar()` without keeping the result (as in `c = getchar();`). Do you have a reason for doing this?

One useful C idiom is:

```
(void) getchar();
```

The cast to void is an indication from the programmer that they know they're discarding the return value.

Comment: This is what I was thinking he was getting at but was waiting around for the code. Without that, this is probably the best/safest guess. Everyone forgets at one time or another that ENTER == '\n'. Taking bets on if "some condition" is != EOF?

Comment: Possibly but neither of these functions returns the char that was read. So we have plenty of guesswork to work out where that EOF would get read.

Comment: Indeed. This should be interesting!

Comment: The thing with the getchar() was just to stop the program. The thing with the one and the two was just to see the order of calling. I posted the gdb output, I hope it helps